# Add bullets to Android's listview

Tags: android, android-listview

What is the best way to add bullet-like images before text? I can set background, but it wants to stretch it and I can't define if I want it to float left or right.
I don't want to add different images, just same style bullets in front of every new string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a custom listview, couldn't find any other way.

Comment: Great,but you could have shared your answer for the benefit of the community.For others,here is a link :http://www.technotalkative.com/android-bullets-in-listview/"

Answer (score 2):

If you need images, use the [`android:drawableLeft`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableLeft) XML attribute (or `drawableRight`, for RTL languages). From code, you can use TextView's [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: But I can only user android:drawableLeft with textview, not with listview.

Comment: If your items contain TextViews this is a viable approach.

Answer (score 0):

Consider pre-pending the [unicode middle dot character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm) to your string.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but I want something more beautiful and custom made :) I have designed it already.